# How to include resources in a Java game on MacOS?

Tags: java, macos, game-development

I have written a game with external resource files (images, sounds, etc..) in Java, which works on Windows when I export the .jar to .exe but not on MacOS when I export the .jar to .app .

I wrote the game in the Eclipse IDE and exported it as a runnable .jar file from there too.

My process for making it run on Windows is I first used an application called "Launch4j" to export from .jar to .exe . Then I made a copy of the folder I developed the game in so that all of the resource files are organized in the right way. Finally, I just put the .exe file in the main directory and it works.

My process for trying to make it run on MacOS was I first used an application called "AppMaker" on a Mac to export from .jar to .app . Then, I made a copy of the folder with the resources and put the .app file in, but it didn't open.

I noticed that if I exported a game without resources to .app and put it in the "Applications" folder on Mac, it worked, so I tried that with the resource game by putting my resource folders inside the actual Applications folder, but it also didn't open.

The only way I actually got a resource Java game to work on Mac was by not exporting it to a .app file at all and just leaving it as a .jar in the folder with the resources, but I really like how you can change the .app icon and it actually shows the file as an application.

Is there any way I can get my .app file with resources to run on MacOS?

Comment: The resources should be embedded _inside_ the JAR file (which is then converted into your platform-specific package). You access these resources with methods such as `Class#getResource(String)` and `Class#getResourceAsStream(String)`. This API is designed to  be application-location independent as it relies on the classpath/modulepath.

Answer (score -1):

I think that a FatJar might help you.
A Fat Jar is an archive which contains both classes and dependencies needed to run an application, here you have some info about it: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/maven/maven-build-fat-jar.html

Comment: Thanks for this! I've never used Maven before, so please excuse my ignorance on the subject, but would compiling a FatJar let me include lots of different files and folder that aren't just class files?

Comment: As long as they are inside the project, they will be included.